# How to recover notebook revision in azure databricks?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have accidentally deleted one of my revision in azure databricks. can I undo my action ? Or there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebooks-use#clear-a-revision-history), you cannot recover deleted revision.

While you delete, it shows warning as This cannot be undone.

[image]